# conflict alias for Set and traditional Scala Set

Tags: scala, set

I am a newbie and I will try to be as clear as possible. This is about odersky scala course.

I have this code below. I understand that this is an alias type to define a Scala Set differently that the traditional way you define a Set in Scala(i.e. a Scala collection).  In this type alias, you give it a integer and returns true (somehow) if the item is contained in the Set.

`type Set = Int => Boolean`

Now I have this piece of code, which returns the result i am expecting.

```
val a = Set("element is contained in set")
type Set = Int => Boolean
a.contains("element is contained in set")
a.contains("element IS NOT contained in set")
```

The result is:

```
a: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(element is contained in set)
defined type alias Set
res0: Boolean = true
res1: Boolean = false
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(element is contained in set)
```

Great! Now i introduce a line in the code.

```
val a = Set("element is contained in set")
type Set = Int => Boolean
a.contains("element is contained in set")
a.contains("element IS NOT contained in set")
**def custom_fc(x:Double): Set[String] = Set(x.toString)**
```

I get the error:

```
Error:(8, 24) A$A235.this.Set does not take type parameters
def custom_fc(x:Double): Set[String] = Set(x.toString)                
Error:(38, 97) inst$A$A.Set does not take type parameters
println("custom_fc: " + MacroPrinter211.printGeneric({import inst$A$A._ ;def `custom_fc(x:Double): Set[String] = Set(x.toString) }).replace("inst$A$A.", ""))`
```

WHY? In this line i am just trying to define a regular fc (i.e. custom_fc) taking Int as input and returning a traditional scala datastructure Set[String]

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
**def custom_fc(x:Double): Set[String] = Set(x.toString)**
```

Why does my custom fc definition interfere with the alias before it?
My custom_fc is

```
custom_fc(x:Double): scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] =
scala.collection.immutable.Set(x.toString)
```

thank you

ps. a way to use `Type Set = Int => Boolean`

```
val belowNegFive: Set = (i) => i < -5
belowNegFive(10)
```

Return a bool dependinf if the elem 10 pertains to the set of numbers below -5.

Comment: For the `custom_fc`, do you mean `def custom_fc(x:Int): scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = scala.collection.immutable.Set(x.toString)`?

Comment: Ok, yes (now I modified the input param from int to double). yes, custom _fc is def custom_fc(x:Double): scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = scala.collection.immutable.Set(x.toString)

Comment: Sill not sure to understand what you're trying to do. Maybe you're looking for a way to rename the Set collection: `import scala.collection.immutable.{Set => OriginalSet}`? Thus: `def custom_fc(x:Int): OriginalSet[String] = OriginalSet(x.toString)`

Comment: I had an exercise in which I was asked to represent Sets as functions.Type Set = Int => Boolean can be used to say whether an item belongs to the Set or not. An example from the exercise (which I could not finish)  val belowNegFive: Set = (i) => i < -5 . So 
belowNegFive(10) returns false.

Comment: Right. So this would be the same thing as substituting the word `Set` for `(Int => Boolean)`. The alias is just giving you a shortcut for representing that. You can still use the type alias `Set` even though it causes conflicts. You just have to be more specific about it in some cases, and the compiler won't really tell you which cases until you mess up

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's going on.

```
val a = Set("element is contained in set")    // a is old library Set()
type Set = Int => Boolean                     // alias now hides library Set()
a.contains("element is contained in set")     // a is still old library
a.contains("element IS NOT contained in set") // and works like it should
def custom_fc(x:Double): Set[String] = Set(x.toString) // WRONG
// new Set alias works different from old library Set()
```

The point of the class is to work with functions. The `Set` alias is a function definition: `Int => Boolean` i.e. takes an `Int` and returns a `Boolean`.

The new `Set` alias is very different from the `Set` collection and can't be used the same way. The `Set` alias does appear to imitate the collection only in that you can query its "content" in the same way, but only when working with `Int` values. Even then, the means of initialization is different.

```
val libSet: collection.Set[Int] = Set(7)  // initialize with a 7

type Set = Int => Boolean
val newSet: Set = (x:Int) => x == 7  // initialize with a 7

libSet(7)  // true
libSet(4)  // false

newSet(7)  // true
newSet(4)  // false
```

The library collection works with other types but the `Set` alias only takes an `Int` and returns a `Boolean`. The new `Set` is a type alias for a function definition. An instance of the new `Set` is a function that imitates only a small subset of what the real `Set` does.

Comment: OK. But in the fc def custom_fc(x:Double): Set[String] = Set(x.toString), I want to use the Set collection (which in this case deals with Strings), not the alias. Can't I use the alias and the old Set collection in the same time? Provided that the old Set collection does NOT use Ints ?

Comment: Of course you can. You just have to tell the compiler which one you're using. After you create the alias, the term `Set` will be the function alias, but `collection.Set` will always be the Standard Library `Set`. `def custom_fc(x:Double): collection.Set[String] = Set(x.toString)`

Comment: How can I do that? I can only do that if I modify the name of the alias? Use something else than Set? To avoid confusion with the collection.Set?

Comment: See the `libSet` definition in my answer, and the last line of my previous comment. When `Set` means two different things you just have to be more specific when referring to the old `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

So you're obviously overriding the Set alias that was already in place. You can fix this by as mentioned in the comments, specifying exactly which Set you mean.

```
def custom_fc(x:Int): scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(x.toString)
```

Also note your type alias is not doing anything. Your calls `a("element is contained in set")
  a("element IS NOT contained in set")` are just calling the apply method on a, which is the same thing as doing `a.apply(...)` and `a.contains(...)` In order to make it easier on yourself and less confusing overall, maybe change the name to `Contains`?

To see an example of **your** set being used, here you go...

```
val setBeingUsed: Set = Set(1).contains
setBeingUsed(1) // true
```

The method which takes in an Int and returns a boolean can be assigned the type `Set` because you aliased that type to it. Then we can call the val we made with type `Set` and essentially do the same thing as calling contains on the set.

Comment: Hello, I modified it. But i do not understand how am I overwriting it? Type Set = Int => Boolean. notice input Int and output Boolean. My custom_fc has input Double and return Set[String]. Different paramters and different name for the two. I do not see overwrite.

Comment: So I'm not entirely sure "how" the compiler figures out / is unable to figure out which type YOU mean, but think about it this way. If you give two things the same name, the compiler DOES have to try to figure out which one you mean. The compiler is smart in some cases, but not that smart. If you want to save yourself and the compiler the trouble, it's easiest to just come up with a non-conflicting name.